# reading an array key from a file, without including the file

Tags: php, arrays, include

I have a php file that contains an array `$myArray`.

```
<?php 
$myArray = array(
  'key1'=>'value1',
  'key2'=>'value2',
);
?>
```

I need to read the value of `key1` from that array. Is there a way to directly read `key1`, without including the whole file? Right now I'm using include like this.

```
$includedArray = include('/path/to/myArray.php');
```

but this is creating a problem for me, because even though I include it under a new name `$includedArray`, it still recognizes the old name `$myArray` which causes naming conflicts.

To solve this problem, I would have changed the included array from a named array ($myArray) to an un-named array, but I can't make changes to the included files. So is there a way to either:

- include the file containing the named array, but have it completely forget the original name (`$myArray`), and have it use ONLY the new name I give it (`$includedArray`)?
- or is there a way to simply read 1 key from the array without including the whole file?

Comment: Have you thought about running that include in a sandbox?  http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php

Comment: include doesn't return a value, so how can this work?

Comment: @msgmash.com The file I'm including has both a named array and at the end does a return. I can't make any changes to that file though. Can only include it.

Comment: @vedarthk Never used namespaces in php before. Can you write an answer?

Comment: There is no simple solution that doesn't involve changing the original files.

Comment: @Brad How resource-intensive is running a sandbox? It's talking about a "php virtual machine". Sounds maybe more than what I need..

Comment: You could unset the original array in the file that includes the file where it is declared

Comment: Could you add the include in a subroutine, which would then return the value you're looking for? That way, variable scope would mean that you didn't over-write the value of the original `$myArray`

Comment: @sameold Do you need that original array further in the code ? Namespaces is a bit complicated one. Another wayout is define `$myArray` as a static member of some class, then there would be name conflicts.

Comment: @sameold, I'm sure it's very resource intensive.  My impression was that you needed a safe way to run PHP and get the result.  If that is not the case, definitely look to other solutions.  You would have to benchmark it to see how bad it is... I don't know offhand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then copy the array to another variable and unset the original array?

**path/to/myNewArray.php**:

```
return call_user_func(function() {
  include "/path/to/myArray.php";
  return $myArray;
});

/*
if (isset($myArray)) {
  $tmpMyArray = $myArray; // storing the $myArray if defined
}

$includedArray = $myArray;
unset($myArray);
if (isset($tmpMyArray)) {
  $myArray = $tmpMyArray; // restoring the previous $myArray
}
*/
```

usage:

```
$whatEver = include("/path/to/myNewArray.php"); // no interference now
```

Comment: Well, I have something like that going on. I was hoping I could call the new array clean, without having to do this.

Comment: You can encapsulating that code block into a new include file, when you return the result: `return $includedArray` and then use it like this: `$myArrayWithFreeName = include "/path/to/myEncapsulatedArray.php";`

Comment: encapsulated it in a function and calling it directly.

Answer (score 2):

If you need shared values but you don't want to use global variables shared with a common included php config file, what about storing those values in a xml or json file?

---

With Json you can load the "array" from a file into a variable of your choice.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

---

Or you could use output buffers, but that does not apply very well for your current use case.

```
    function ob_include_to_string($filename)
    {
        ob_start();                                         // Starts the 'output buffer'
        include($filename);                                 // Includes the file
        $return_variable = ob_get_contents();               // Sets an variable to keep the content of the echo'ed out content
        ob_end_clean();                                     // Ends and deletes the 'output buffer'; "cleans it up"
        return $return_variable;                            // Returns the variable with the content
    }
```

---

What about changing your config file to:

```
<?php 
$myArray = array(
  'key1'=>'value1',
  'key2'=>'value2',
);

echo json_encode($myArray);
?>
```

And then you could do:

```
$newArray = json_decode(ob_include_to_string('config.php'));
```

Comment: This is wrong ... `ob_get_contents()` would only return value if `$filename` is outputting content with print or echo or similar .. it would not return the array as a varriable

Comment: I'm sorry, what was I thinking... Not very logical in this use case.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1

Take advantage of `function scope`

```
$myArray = arrayInclude("myArray.php");
var_dump($myArray);

function arrayInclude($file)
{
    include $file;
    return $myArray;    
}
```

Output

```
array
  'key1' => string 'foo1' (length=4)
  'key2' => string 'foo2' (length=4)
```

**myArray.php**

```
$myArray = array (

                'key1' => 'foo1',
                'key2' => 'foo2'
        );
```

### Method 2

Using   `function` & `namespace`

**a.php**

```
include 'b.php';
include 'c.php';

$myArray = call_user_func ( 'b\myArray' );

var_dump ( $myArray );

$myArray = call_user_func ( 'c\myArray' );

var_dump ( $myArray );
```

Output

```
array
  'key1' => string 'foo1' (length=4)
  'key2' => string 'foo2' (length=4)
array
  'key1' => string 'bar1' (length=4)
  'key2' => string 'bar2' (length=4)
```

**b.php**

```
namespace b;

    function myArray() {
        return array (

                'key1' => 'foo1',
                'key2' => 'foo2'
        );

    }
```

**c.php**

```
namespace c;

function myArray() {
    return array (

            'key1' => 'bar1',
            'key2' => 'bar2' 
    );

}
```

Comment: I think so, declaring it as a static variable of a class would be an efficient way to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

array.php

```
<?php
    class MyArray {
        public static $myArray = array('key1' => value1, 'key2' => value2);
    }
?>
```

other.php

```
<?php
    include('array.php');

    //Access the value as
    MyArray::$myArray['key1'];
?>
```